# Creating a dataframe from paragraph text scraped from website in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a website that has numerous different information I want in paragraphs. I got this to work perfect... However, I don't understand how to break the text up and create a dataframe.

**Website :**[Website I want Scraped](https://www.nj.gov/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml)

**Code:**

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml"

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)


p_nodes<-webpage%>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//p')%>%
  html_text()

#replace multiple whitespaces with single space
p_nodes<- gsub('\\s+',' ',p_nodes)
#trim spaces from ends of elements
p_nodes <- trimws(p_nodes)
#drop blank elements
p_nodes <- p_nodes[p_nodes != '']
```

**How I want the dataframe to look:**

[image]

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I tried to extract each piece of information separately and then make the dataframe like that but it doesn't work since most of the info is stored in the p tag. I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Since each lines are really different, you will need some parsing script taking into account a lot of different cases and exceptions. If you need to run it only once, it will be faster to cut it by hand (create a vector of string from each line and then use `rbind`)

Comment: I'd suggest using `html` tags and `regex` in a custom function, e.g. you could use `tr~ tr+ tr p , td+ p` to get all those individual contact and then `regex` to extract the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof-of-concept (based on what I wrote in the comment):

**Code**

```
lapply(c('data.table', 'httr', 'rvest'), library, character.only = T)

tags <- 'tr:nth-child(6) td , tr~ tr+ tr p , td+ p'
burl <- 'https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml'

url_text <- read_html(burl)

chunks <- url_text %>% html_nodes(tags) %>% html_text()

coordFunc <- function(chunk){
  patter_lat <- 'Longitude:.*(-[[:digit:]]{1,2}.[[:digit:]]{0,15})'
  ret <- regmatches(x = chunk, m = regexec(pattern = patter_lat, text = chunk))
  return(ret[[1]][2])
}

longitudes <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(chunks, coordFunc)))
```

**Output**

```
# using 'cat' to make the output easier to read 
> cat(chunks[14])
Mt.    Laurel DOT
                  Rt. 38, East
                  1/4 mile East of Rt. 295
                  Mt. Laurel Open 24 Hrs
                  Unleaded / Diesel
                  856-235-3096Latitude:  39.96744662Longitude: -74.88930386 


> longitudes[14]
[1] -74.8893
```

If you do not coerce `longitudes` to be `numeric`, you get:

```
longitudes <- (unlist(lapply(chunks, coordFunc)))
> longitudes[14]
[1] "-74.88930386"
```

I chose the longitude as a proof-of-concept but you can modify your function to extract all relevant bits in a single call. For getting the right `tag` you can use SelectorGadget extension (works well in Chrome for me). Alliteratively most browsers let you 'inspect element' to get the `html` tag. The function could return the extracted values in a `data.table` which can then be combined into one using `rbindlist`.

You could even advance pages programatically to scrape the entire website - be sure to check with the usage policy (it's generally frowned upon or restricted to scrape websites).

**Edit**

the text is not structured the same way throughout the webpage so you'll need to spend more time examining what exceptions can take place.

Here's a new function to resolve each chunk into separate lines and then you can try to use additional regular expressions to get what you want.

```
newfunc <- function(chunk){
  # Each chunk is a couple of lines. First, we split at '\r\n' using strsplit
  # the output is a list so we use 'unlist' to get a vector 
  # then use 'trimws' to remove whitespace around it - try out each of these functions
  # separately to understand what is going on. The final output here is a vector. 
  txt <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(chunk, '\r\n'))) 
  return(txt)
}
```

This returns the 'text' contained in each chunk as a vector of separate lines. Taking a look at the number of lines in the first 20 chunks, you can see it is not the same:

```
> unlist(lapply(chunks[1:20], function(z) length(newfunc(z))))
 [1] 5 6 5 7 5 5 5 5 5 4 1 6 6 6 5 1 1 1 5 6
```

A good way to resolve this would be to put in a conditional statement based on the number of lines of text in each chunk, e.g. in `newfunc` you could add:

```
if(length(txt) == 1){
return(NULL)
}
```

This is because that is for the entries that don't have any text in them. since this a proof of concept I haven't checked all entries but there's some simple logic:

1. The first line is typically the name
2. the coordinates are in the last line
3. The fuel can be either `unleaded` or `diesel`. You can `grep` on these two strings to see what each depot offers. e.g. `grepl('diesel', newfunc(chunks[12]))`
4. Another approach would be to use a different set of `html` tags e.g. all coorindates and opening hours are in boldface and have the tag `strong`. You can extract those separately and then use regular expressions to get what you want.
5. You could search for `24(Hrs|Hours)` to first extract all sites that are open 24 hours and then use selective `regex` on the remainder to get their operating times.

There is no simple easy answer with most web-scraping, you have to find patterns and then apply some logic based on that. Only on the most structured websites will you find something that works for the entire page/range.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. I just don't understand how to get all the other parts and make a nice dataframe. I don't understand how you got this part:  patter_lat <- 'Longitude:.*(-[[:digit:]]{1,2}.[[:digit:]]{0,15})'

Comment: @NBE the part  you're referring to is regular expressions e.g. `[[:digit:]]` is telling R that we expect a digit. Here's a good beginner's reference on regular expressions: https://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html `regmatches` and `regexec` are slightly advanced functions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try! So once I figure out the regular expressions for the other parts, I can combine them and make a dataframe?

Comment: @nbe yes, I've added some more details in my answer. Hopefully that helps but there's some elbow grease you need to put in yourself :) If the answer is helpful, please upvote or consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tidyverse package (stringr, tibble, purrr)

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
url <- "https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/administration/statewide-support/motor-fuel-locations.shtml"
#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)
p_nodes<-webpage%>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//p')%>%
  html_text()
# Split on new line
l = p_nodes %>% stringr::str_split(pattern = "\r\n")
var1 = sapply(l, `[`, 1) # replace var by the name you want
var2 = sapply(l, `[`, 2)
var3 = sapply(l, `[`, 3)
var4 = sapply(l, `[`, 4)
var5 = sapply(l, `[`, 5)
t = tibble(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5) # make tibble
t = t %>% filter(!is.na(var2)) # delete useless lines
purrr::map_dfr(t,trimws) # delete blanks
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.. however, var 3 to var 5 is messed up. How can I fix this?

Comment: It has a bunch of info clumped together instead of having in separate columns like in the picture above